# Bug adding char array (terminated by a space) to a string in c++.

Tags: c++

I get a strange output when trying to concatenate a string to a ' ' terminated char array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{    
    char someCharArray[6] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' '};
    string someString = "world!";
    cout << someCharArray + someString << endl;
}
```

will return:

```
Hello gR
world!
```

but I have noticed that if I change the size of the array to `7` and beyond, the output will be fine `Hello world!`. Why is that? The output will also be fine if I add the space in the string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{    
    char someCharArray[5] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    string someString = " world!";
    cout << someCharArray + someString << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your char array isn't null-terminated and is therefore not a string. If you omit the size altogether and specify the value as a string, not individual chars, the compiler will null-terminate it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/operator+/) which requires the C string when used with operator+ to be null terminated: "If of type charT*, it shall point to a null-terminated character sequence."  Yours is not null terminated.  Try adding an extra element at the end of the char array that is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your char array is not 0 terminated, but plain c-strings must be 0 terminated:

```
    char someCharArray[7] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 0};
```

This should work.

Comment: Although this does work, unless you have a good reason for wanting to do this it's silly when `char someCharArray = "Hello";` does the same thing without making you count characters.

Comment: @Donnie: sometimes you need such character arrays if you want to  control exactly the memory requirements, especially when programming a microcontroller.

Comment: @ul90: My code uses the same amount of memory, exactly, and also results in a character array.  If you need to represent a string constant, it takes a certain amount of memory.